# Finding coordinates of point located on a curve in an image using Python

Tags: python, image-processing, coordinates

I have an image and I want to find the coordinates of some points that are located on a curve in this image. Please take a look at the image.
The red points are the points that I need to calculate their coordinates. Could you please tell me how I can do it in Python?
Thank in advance for your help.
Best

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the image to HSV and separate out the red dots. Then getting its coordinates is simple by finding contours and their moments. In case you are using OpenCV -

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frame=cv2.imread("dots.jpg")
dots=np.zeros_like(frame)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_hsv = np.array([112, 176, 174])
higher_hsv = np.array([179,210,215])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hsv, higher_hsv)

cnts, h = cv2.findContours( mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
mnts  = [cv2.moments(cnt) for cnt in cnts]

centroids = [( int(round(m['m10']/m['m00'])),int(round(m['m01']/m['m00'])) ) for m in mnts]


for c in centroids:
    cv2.circle(dots,c,5,(0,255,0))
    print c

cv2.imshow('red_dots', dots)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However it was not what I was looking for. Firstly, I could not figure out these coordinates have been calculated with respect to what origin! Anyway, I am sorry for not mentioning it in my question but I wanted the coordinates of the red dots with respect to the center of the arc that the dots are located on (Lets say the coordinate of the center is (0,0). In this case the coordinates of the points (dots) should be zero because they are located on the lower half-circle. I'd appreciate your time looking into it again.

Comment: You can check about the hough circles [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html). These might be the points on one circle. You can easily get the center of that hough circle as shown in the link. Once you have the center, subtract that from the printed coordinates and you'll get the coordinates with respect to the center of arc.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the Hough Circle Transform as you said. But my question still exists. Could you please clarify the location of the origin and also the X&Y-Axis that you calculated these coordinates with respect to?

Comment: The coordinates are with respect to the image. ie origin is the first pixel (0,0) of the image.